# Due to a merger we have two companies both with M365 tenants, one with a mature SharePoint Online environment, one without

Tags: sharepoint-online, merge

**Company A**: They have a mature SharePoint 365 environment over ten years old with nearly 2tb of data.

**Company B**: is the dominant organisation with Microsoft 365 but don't use SharePoint 365, but often require Guest access to the 'Company A' SharePoint, which can get messy as some users are 'Read Only' and others are 'Members'.

Both organisations have their own domains with 'Company B' being the much bigger organisation and eventually the main domain for all users.

Is there a process for merging the SharePoint environment from 'Company A' with the 'Company B' tenant?

Thank you in advance I hope this makes sense.

Comment: We do not have a way to merge two SharePoint Online tenants. The only solution is to migrate content from one tenant to the other. You can utilize a third party tool for this migration.